# Using both apply() and commit() in sharedpreference

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout, sharedpreferences

```
sharedPreferencesEditor.putStringSet("Saved", set).apply();
                sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
                if(sharedPreferencesEditor.commit()){
                    Toast.makeText(BankActivity.this, "Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Is it better to use both apply() and commit() method for regular changing text in shared preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- commit() is instantaneous but performs disk writes.
- commit() - returns boolean value.
- commit() returns true if the save works, false otherwise and blocking
  the UI thread until complete action.
- apply() was added as the android dev team noticed that most no one
  took notice of the return value, so apply is faster.
- apply() is asynchronous.

Comment: thanks! want instantaneous action.So commit()             sharedPreferencesEditor.putStringSet("Saved", set).commit();

Answer (score 1):

No, you should one or the other. It really depends on what you're doing, but in general you want to use `.apply()`.

`.apply()` will apply your changes in the background at a later time; whereas `.commit()` will apply your changes on the current thread, at that time right away.

So, if you need to save something right away, and don't mind blocking the UI thread, you can use `.commit()`, but `.apply()` will work better in 95% of cases.

Comment: thanks! i prefer changes happen on current thread at right away..Gonna change it tosharedPreferencesEditor.putStringSet("Saved", set).commit();